# Given a non-symmetric matrix $A$, when does $x^TAx<0$ implies existence of a eigenvalue with negative real part?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a (possibly) non-symmetric matrix, and there exists a vector $x$ such that $x^TAx<0$. Under what further conditions can one conclude that there exists an eigenvalue with negative real part?